# How to get the final json object from a response using promise.all?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am using promise.all to go and fetch three endpoints.

The promise.all gives me back an array of responses that looks like this:

```
0: Response {type: "basic", url: "https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/af3910a6-429f-4c74-9ad5-dfe1c4aa04f2", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}
1: Response {type: "basic", url: "https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/6bc92fdd-b0f4-4286-ad71-1f99fb4a0d1e", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}
2: Response {type: "basic", url: "https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/f25fa661-3073-414d-968a-ab062e3065f7", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}
```

But I cant get the actuall json of those endpoints, I always endup with an array of more promises.

The part of the code where im having the issue is at the bottom of the function and the array of responses is saved in a variable called: `linksToSpecieResponses`

I have tried maping over the array of responses and using .json() and also them after that like this:

`linksToSpecieResponses.forEach( response => response.json().then( x => results.push(x) ))`

But it doesnt work.

Any ideas what do i have to do in order to get the actual json of those reponses?

Here is the code in codepen: https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/OJJzKoM?editors=0010

And this is the code:

```
const TITLE = 'Princess Mononoke'
const SPECIE = 'God'
const SOECIES_URL = 'htps://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/species/b5a92d0e-5fb4-43d4-ba60-c012135958e4'

async function getMoro(url) {
  const moviesResponse = await fetch(url)
  const movies = await moviesResponse.json()
  const movie = movies.find(movie => movie.title === TITLE)

  const speciesOfMoviePromises = movie.species.map(async url => await fetch(url))
  const speciesOfMovieResponses = await Promise.all(speciesOfMoviePromises)

  let speciesLinks = []
  for(let i = 0 ; i<speciesOfMovieResponses.length ; i++){
   speciesLinks.push( await speciesOfMovieResponses[i].json() )
  }

  const linksToSpecie = speciesLinks.map(async x =>  await fetch(x.id))
  const linksToSpecieResponses = await Promise.all(linksToSpecie)
  // What should i do with this array of promises?
  console.log('linksToSpecieResponses: ', linksToSpecieResponses)

  return await linksToSpecieResponses
}

getMoro('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films')
```

Comment: I think you're missing a line like: `const jsonFromResponses = await Promise.all(linksToSpecieResponses.map(response => response.json())`

Comment: Some of your requests are throwing uncaught 403s. The URL you're hitting is `https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/f25fa661-3073-414d-968a-ab062e3065f7` which is a bad URL. I think some of your requests are missing the base URL. What is your expected result (please describe what you're doing here/trying to achieve)? Thanks.